# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value' | Pynput doesn't allow me to use the mouse and keyboard at the same time

Tags: python, pynput

I have a problem with Pynput, whenever i use both the mouse and keyboard functions together the output responds with:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I've tried tried to find a solution but nothing that i can find has worked. I've attached my script, the error only seems to happen when im using both the mouse and keyboard functions.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()
keyboard = Controller()

key1 = "s"
key2= "t"
key3 = "o"
key4 = "p"

mouse.position = (-1180, 153)
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
keyboard.press(key1)
keyboard.release(key1)
keyboard.press(key2)
keyboard.release(key2)
keyboard.press(key3)
keyboard.release(key3)
keyboard.press(key4)
keyboard.release(key4)
```

Thank You - Connor

Comment: You are importing `Controller` from two different modules.  The name is only going to refer to the most recent value assigned to it, which is `pynput.mouse.Controller` in this case.

Comment: Import the second controller with an alias: `from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MController`

Comment: @Mike67 I've changed the mouse variable to MController but it still doesn't seem to work. I've probably done something really stupid.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you are importing two classes with the same name. Use an alias to differentiate them in the code.

This code works as expected:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MController  # alias
mouse = MController()
keyboard = Controller()

key1 = "s"
key2= "t"
key3 = "o"
key4 = "p"

mouse.position = (-1180, 153)
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
keyboard.press(key1)
keyboard.release(key1)
keyboard.press(key2)
keyboard.release(key2)
keyboard.press(key3)
keyboard.release(key3)
keyboard.press(key4)
keyboard.release(key4)
```